# RXJS Share state between merge streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I need to make API call for get/set method. But these Service need previous state to make a next call.
In this pattern, in state prop I wanted to maintain previous state of this stream so that when I make next get/set call I can pass the previous state to service. And once I receive the response from service it will update state for next iteration.

But problem is this merge state is executing get$ and set$ map even before sending value with next.
Can someone please suggest what am I missing here?

```
const { Subject, merge} = require('rxjs');
const { map,switchMap,scan } = require('rxjs/operators');

function stream(){
  
  const get$= new Subject()
  const set$= new Subject()
  
  const store$=merge(
    get$.pipe(
      map(options=>{
        return acc=>{
          
          return {
            state:{…acc.state},
            service:state=>{
              return getCall(options,state)
            }
          }
        }
        
      })
    ),
    set$.pipe(
      map(options=>{
        return acc=>{
          
          return {
            state:{…acc.state},
            service:state=>{
              return setCall(options,state)
            }
          }
        }
        
      })
    )
    
  ).pipe(
    scan((acc,update)=>{
      return update(acc)
    },{state:{},service:()=>{}}),
    switchMap(
      ({state,service})=>{
        return service(state)
      }
    )
  )
  
  return {
    get:options=>{
      get$.next(options)
      return store$
    },
    set:options=>{
      set$.next(options)
      return store$
    }
  }
}
const{get,set}=stream()
get({prop:1}).subscribe(console.log)
set({prop:2}).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: could you describe more what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do ! can you add more details here ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added my senario